Can I start an S-Corp to donate my income to so it doesn't show I earn income while the S-Corp pays taxes ,running biz that is donating to charities
People that get financial help like public assistance or social security, if they get a financial gift from others, or maybe they get lucky and sell one song lyrics, or sell a painting that is a on-again-off-again hobby, can lose their assistance / their benefits. The royalties for the song could be cents but I was told it would be seen as a job I could make a living at and I would lose my benefits (true).  So, I am not a person trying to hide that I am working a full time job or anything and collecting benefits I shouldnt be. I just have periodic bouts of energy with my little hobbies and I would like to try selling a painting or song lyrics, which if they became popular, of course I wouldn't need benefits.
If I had an S-Corp, perhaps I could donate my time to it and it could pay taxes, run things, and it's primary business could be to donate money to charities. And at some point in the future, I could collect something down the line maybe but I'd be happy that the money would go to charity. I cannot earn it and send it right to charity, they'd still take away my benefits. With a corporation the IRS still gets taxes and if the biz starts making money so I could quit recieving my benefits, I could quit those and collect something, donations myself that I would have to then report. Living on a fixed income, disabled, doesn't give me the ability to just say oh I'll just quit and try my hobbies for awhile.

I doubt it is possible, but I'm interested to see if there are other ways. Generally you are allowed some moderate income before benefits are cut off, but it may depend on the benefits. And S-Corps are generally treated as pass-through (their income is your income) so it should be considered in your eligibility.

If you only want the corporation to donate to charities, the simpler solution is a donor advised fund (DAF). They do most of the paperwork. You just donate to them as if they were a charity, then tell them what actual charities you want the money sent to, when and how often. One of the huge advantages is that since most DAFs accept donations of equities, you can take advantage of that mechanism for avoiding capital gains tax even if the ultimate charity you want to give to isn't set up to handle that. For me, this is well worth the deductible donation of $100/year to the DAF itself.

Your question is extremely difficult to understand, but I think it boils down to "If I work through an S-Corp, is it considered "working" for taxes and benefits?".
The answer to that is resounding yes. It doesn't matter how you're organizing your business, you're working. Whether it is material enough to lose benefits depends on what the benefit is and what the conditions are.
S-Corps are "disregarded entities" for tax purposes and show up on your individual tax return, they do not change the nature, timing, or treatment of the income. In addition you may be required to pay yourself a reasonable salary for the contributions of time and work made to the S-Corp. S-Corp cannot donate anything to charity, since charitable contribution deduction only shows up on the underlying entity tax return (yours).
